# iOS- UImageView scale animation dose not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, imageview

I want to create an animation that the imageView will become more and more small and transparent, then disappear. I tried below code, it doesn't work, when run it will grow from 0.01 size to the original size. I can't figure out where the problem is.

Thank you very much!

```
[UIView animationWithDuration:2 animations:^{
[imageview setTransform:(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01,0.01))];
[imageview setAlpha:0];
}
completion:^(BOOL finished){
[imageview removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

Comment: in which method u r calling this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
[UIView animationWithDuration:2 animations:^{
CGAffineTransform *transform =  CGAffineTransformScale(imageView.transform, 0.01, 0.01);
[imageview setTransform:transform];
[imageview setAlpha:0];
}
completion:^(BOOL finished){
[imageview removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

This will take in consider the existing imageView transform. (Is there a chance you already applied transform to this imageView?)

An other thing you can try is to add: `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState`
as an option to the animation method. You will have to use :

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your method name seems to be incorrect. Correct method is **animateWithDuration**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
```